# ¿porqué no hace efecto la hoja de estilos que enlace y la imagen del icono de la página?

Tags: html, css

Como verán en la siguiente imagen tengo una carpeta de páginas principales
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

son 18 páginas enlazadas a la pagina home.html [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa página home tiene enlazada una hoja de estilos y una imagen para el icono de la página
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A lo cual si funciona este es el resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada página es una imagen de vídeo que al hacer clic me lleva a una de las páginas, que estan enlazadas a home, pero el resultado es el siguiente,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta página al igual que todas las 18 tiene enlazadas la hoja de estilo y el icono de la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero como ven en la imagen anterior el problema es que sale simple, como si no tuviera enlazada ninguna hoja de estilo y como si el icono no tuviera extensión mas todas las 18 hojas tinen lo siguiente

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>enviar mensaje masivo</title>
  

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imagenes/alex.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
 
<header>
```

¿Sucederá este problema porque yo copié y pegue la información?

Comment: la ubicaciones del icono es correcta así como la de la hoja de estilos y no han cambiado

Comment: Pregunta! Ya que estás programando en Sublime text ¿me lo recomiendas para programar en HTML? Ah respondiendo a tu problema: Intenta usar una ruta relativa (como te lo han dicho anteriores respuestas a la mía). No tengo que especificar porque ya lo hicieron jeje :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que tus paginas "enlazadas" están en la carpeta "Páginas principales", y las sigues buscando así `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">` pero ya que están de esta forma, el buscador no la encuentra, lo que tienes que hacer es buscar tus estilos con ruta relativa ../ así: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">` de esta forma si cargará al DOM de la página.

Comment: la carpeta principal de mi proyecto se llama alexandrawp y dentro esta home.html y la carpeta paginas principales y la carpeta css dentro de la cual esta la hoja de estilo y la carpeta imagenes dentro de la cual esta alex.ico.

Comment: ¿Cómo deberia escribir la ruta?

Comment: me explicas mas sobre lo que es dom y su relación con las rutas relativas? y cual es el oponente de rutas relativas?, es decir que tipo de ruta estaba utilizando yo, y porque esta mal?

Comment: Esta bien, pero eso requiere una nueva respuesta

Comment: una nueva respuesta de parte mia o suya?

Comment: y con el logotipo también agrego los dos puntos? mi directorio es así todo esta en alexandrawp dentro hay una carpeta imagenes donde esta el icono y dentro de alexandrawp esta la carpeta paginas principales

Comment: **Ruta absoluta** `"https://url.com/archivo.extension"` o `"c://documentos/carpeta/archivo.extension"`, **ruta relativa:** `"carpeta/archivo.extension"`. Siempre has manejado rutas relativas, a lo que se refieren es que cuando haces referencia al css y el archivo que lo llama no esta en la misma carpeta del home sino dentro de otra carpeta se usa: `../` para devolver la ruta relativa a la carpeta raíz.

Answer (score 1):

**DOM**
Acorde al W3C el Modelo de Objetos del Documento es una interfaz de programación de aplicaciones (API) para documentos validos HTML y bien construidos XML. Define la estructura lógica de los documentos y el modo en que se accede y manipula.

El DOM permite un acceso a la estructura de una página HTML mediante el mapeo de los elementos de esta página en un árbol de nodos. Cada elemento se convierte en un nodo y cada porción de texto en un nodo de texto. Para comprender más fácilmente véase el siguiente ejemplo:

```html
<body>
<p>Esto es un párrafo que contiene <a href="#">un enlace</a> en el medio. </p>
<ul>
<li>Primer punto en la lista</li>
<li>Otro punto en la lista</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Como puede verse un elemento [a] se encuentra localizado dentro de un elemento [p] del HTML, convirtiéndose en un nodo hijo, o simplemente hijo del nodo [p], de manera similar [p] es el nodo padre. Los dos nodos li son hijos del mismo padre, llamándose nodos hermanos o simplemente hermanos.

Es importante comprender la diferencia entre elementos y nodos de textos. Los elementos comúnmente son asociados a las etiquetas. En HTML todas las etiquetas son elementos, tales como < p>, < img> y < div> por lo que tienen atributos y contienes nodos hijos. Sin embargo, los nodos de textos no poseen atributos e hijos.

Lo que tienes que comprender son las rutas absolutas y relativas. Tu carpeta "Páginas principales" en las cuales pones tus páginas están mas adentro que tu página HOME por ello la ruta desde el `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">` que pusiste busca dentro de la carpeta "Páginas principales" en la cual no hay nada, para eso le pones esto "../" para indicar que debe retroceder al directorio inmediato superior. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: y que pasaria si yo pusiera dentro de la ruta paginas principales la hoja de estilos, ya no seria necesario agrega ../ ?

Comment: otra solución esque las paginas estuvieran junto con home? entonces la ruta que estaba poniendo yo sin los puntos es para buscar una carpeta inmediata inferior?

Comment: Esta bien a que hayas puesto las páginas en una carpeta especial, eso les da más orden, no te compliques mucho por la ruta, al fin y al cabo son solo la referencia a la ubicación de tus recursos, eso siempre puede variar.

Answer (score 0):

No te enredes con las rutas, por el momento ten en cuenta que lo que estas usando son rutas relativas, o sea que a partir del archivo en donde te encuentra, buscas otro archivo que quieras enlazar. Estas escribiendo mal las rutas en tus "18 paginas principales" lo correcto es lo siguiente

```
<head>
   <title>enviar mensaje masivo</title>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../imagenes/alex.ico">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">
</head>
```

Utilizas ".." para regresar un carpeta y "/" para meterte a una carpeta o para tomar un archivo.

te lo pongo simple para que lo comprendas, dices:
estoy en el archivo "enviar mensaje masivo.html" estoy dentro de la carpeta "paginas principales", necesito regresar una carpeta atrás pongo "..", meterme a la carpeta "css", pongo "/" y luego necesito el archivo "estilos.css" pongo de nuevo "/". Y asi obtienes la ruta correcta "../css/estilos.css"